# How to format strings in an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of strings that I need to format in a certain order, the array is as follows with the index of each string

```
array = [
[0] "Bonk  Radek  S  Male  Green  6/3/1978",
[1] "Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  Blue  6/3/1975",
[2] "Smith  Steve  D  Male  Red  3/3/1985"
]
```

at the moment each string is formatted:

Last Name, First Name, Middle, Gender, Fav Color, Birth Date

I need to write code that will format it:

last name, first name, middle, gender, date of birth, favorite color

How do I rearrange the strings to be in the format I want and return the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression substitution ([`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub)):

```
array = [
  "Bonk  Radek  S  Male  Green  6/3/1978",
  "Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  Blue  6/3/1975",
  "Smith  Steve  D  Male  Red  3/3/1985"
]
array.map { |s| s.sub(/(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)$/, '\3\2\1') }
# => [
#     "Bonk  Radek  S  Male  6/3/1978  Green",
#     "Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  6/3/1975  Blue",
#     "Smith  Steve  D  Male  3/3/1985  Red"
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though to beautify code one might want to introduce some heuristics for data remapping, I would stuck with simple hardcoded reorder:

```
array = [ 
  "Bonk  Radek  S  Male  Green  6/3/1978", 
  "Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  Blue  6/3/1975", 
  "Smith  Steve  D  Male  Red  3/3/1985"
]
array.map { |p| 
  data = p.split(/\s+/);
  [data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[5],data[4]].join(', ') 
}

#=> [
#  [0] "Bonk, Radek, S, Male, 6/3/1978, Green",
#  [1] "Bouillon, Francis, G, Male, 6/3/1975, Blue",
#  [2] "Smith, Steve, D, Male, 3/3/1985, Red"
#]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
a = array.map(&:split).transpose
a[-1], a[-2] = a[-2], a[-1]
a.transpose.map { |v| v.join('  ') }
  #=> ["Bonk  Radek  S  Male  6/3/1978  Green",
  #    "Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  6/3/1975  Blue",
  #    "Smith  Steve  D  Male  3/3/1985  Red"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider splitting the logic out into smaller pieces and introduce other simple objects instead of just trying to stick to Ruby `String`

```
require 'ostruct'

Person = Struct.new(:surname, :forename, :initial, :gender, :colour, :date_of_birth)

array = [
"Bonk  Radek  S  Male  Green  6/3/1978",
"Bouillon  Francis  G  Male  Blue  6/3/1975",
"Smith  Steve  D  Male  Red  3/3/1985"
].map { |o| Person.new(*o.split(/\s+/)) }

array.each do |person|
  puts "%{surname} %{forename} %{initial} %{gender} %{date_of_birth} %{colour}" % person.to_h
end
```

- I start by creating a basic class that will represent a person so there will be one instance per line.
- Next I map each line into one of these Person objects
- Then I just create a format string and throw the `to_h` of a person into it

Breaking this down with real objects gives you more flexibility in the long run like if you wanted to sort on date you would need to parse those date strings into real objects and your `Person` object could handle that